# Create services dynamically in azure service fabric

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I want to know if it's possible to create multiple service fabric services from inside another service?

The scenario where I require this is inside a MMO game where a group of players decide to fight another group of players inside a World of Warcraft style battleground arena. These instances needs to be created dynamically and the IP and port address for these service applications need to be exposed to the connecting player somehow.

I have managed to create the service with the information provided by the links below:

http://www.codeguru.com/azure_activities/obtaining-reliability-and-scalability-in-azure-service-fabric.html

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-rest-based-application-lifecycle-sample/

The service is created but only one can be created at a time, and I don't know how to extract the IP and port information from the created service.

Would service groups be a possible solution to this?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicegroupmanagementclient.aspx

Comment: Have you considered using actors for that? Sounds like a perfect match for your scenario: just create a new `ActorProxy` and send a message to the new actor.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. Create a new Actor for each instance that is required. The only thing that worries me, will the messaging overhead not be to high for a low ping scenario?

Comment: Why do you think that the overhead for actors would be significantly higher than for services? In any case, you should run tests for your workloads and your latency requirements.

Comment: Would possibly be the same, thanks for the answer Mikhail. Busy doing a test implementation now.

Comment: Yes, you can. Thanks Mikhail!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using the Actor model for that. Multi-player game backend is one of the classic scenarios for actor-based systems. So, whenever you need to create a new group of players

1. Pick an ID for the new group. You will address the new group by this ID.
2. Create a new `ActorProxy` with this ID and send a message to the new actor.

Service Fabric will make all the startup, communication and lifetime management work for you. No need to know IP or any network details.